# Daily emails based on date field in Account object (Apex Class) - help?

Tags: scheduled-apex

I'm trying to create an Apex Class that checks all Account records on a daily basis and sends an email to the email field on ones that have a review due on that date.

For example:
Vendor ABC Pty Ltd has opted in for reviews (Vendor Review: Reminders = true), has an annual review date set in their record (Vendor Review: Date = 17/02/2019), and an email address set in their record (Vendor Review: Email = abc@test.com).

Here is my code:

```
global class VendorReviewCronJob implements Schedulable{ 

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        sendmail();
    }

    public List<Id> getVendorReviewEmailAddresses(Integer Month, Integer Day) 
    { 
        List<Id> mailToIds = new List<Id>();

        Account[] a = [SELECT Id, Vendor_Review_Email__c, Vendor_Review_Date__c, Vendor_Review_Reminders__c
                        FROM Account 
                        WHERE DAY_IN_MONTH(Vendor_Review_Date__c) = : Day 
                        AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Vendor_Review_Date__c) = : Month   
                        ];

        for(Account recipient : a) {

                System.Debug('\n*******Found VendorReview Recipient');

                if (recipient.Vendor_Review_Reminders__c == true)
                {
                    mailToIds.add(recipient.Id);
                    System.Debug('\n*******Recipient: '+ recipient.Vendor_Review_Email__c);

                } else {
                    System.Debug('\n*******NO Recipient');
                }

        }

        return mailToIds;
    }




    public void sendMail() 
    {

        String debugAddress = 'eyewell@salesforce.com';
        String VendorReviewEmailTemplateName = 'User_Vendor_Review_Required';       
        String debugMessage;
        String[] toAddresses;

        Integer DayOfEvent   = date.today().day();
        Integer MonthOfEvent = date.today().month();

        List<Id> VendorReviewIdsList = getVendorReviewEmailAddresses(MonthOfEvent,DayOfEvent);

        EmailTemplate VendorReviewTemplate = [select Id,Name,Subject,body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = :VendorReviewEmailTemplateName];

        if(VendorReviewTemplate != null && VendorReviewIdsList.isEmpty() == false)
        {

            Messaging.MassEmailMessage VendorReviewMail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();

            VendorReviewMail.setTargetObjectIds(VendorReviewIdsList);
            VendorReviewMail.setTemplateId(VendorReviewTemplate.Id);
            VendorReviewMail.setUseSignature(false);
            VendorReviewMail.setSaveAsActivity(true);

            try {
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] { VendorReviewMail });
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Debug(e);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.Debug('VendorReviewCronJob:sendMail(): Either an email template could not be found, or no Account has a Vendor Review today');
        }


    }
```

}

I've scheduled the apex class to run daily, but although it's showing that it has run, the emails for the reviews due that day haven't sent, and I also haven't received the confirmation email of how many were sent.

Admittedly, I got the base of the code from a mailer that was checking for birthdays on a Contact object, but I felt the same principles still applied.

Can anybody see where I've gone wrong?

UPDATED CODE (as per David's suggestion)

```
global class VendorReviewCronJob implements Schedulable{ 

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        sendmail();
    }

    public List<Id> getVendorReviewEmailAddresses(Integer Month, Integer Day) 
    { 
        List<Id> mailToIds = new List<Id>();

        Account[] c = [SELECT Id, Vendor_Review_Email__c, Vendor_Review_Date__c, Vendor_Review_Reminders__c
                        FROM Account 
                        WHERE DAY_IN_MONTH(Vendor_Review_Date__c) = : Day 
                        AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Vendor_Review_Date__c) = : Month   
                        ];

        for(Account recipient : c) {

                System.Debug('\n*******Found VendorReview Recipient');

                if (recipient.Vendor_Review_Reminders__c == true)
                {
                    mailToIds.add(recipient.Id);
                    System.Debug('\n*******Recipient: '+ recipient.Vendor_Review_Email__c);

                } else {
                    System.Debug('\n*******NO Recipient');
                }

        }

        return mailToIds;
    }

    public void sendMail() 
    {         
        String debugAddress = 'itsupport@recruitwest.com.au';
        String VendorReviewEmailTemplateName = 'User_Vendor_Review_Required';
        String debugMessage;
        String[] toAddresses;

        Integer DayOfEvent   = date.today().day();
        Integer MonthOfEvent = date.today().month();

        List<Id> VendorReviewIdsList = getVendorReviewEmailAddresses(MonthOfEvent,DayOfEvent);

        EmailTemplate vendorreviewTemplate = [select Id,Name,Subject,body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = :VendorReviewEmailTemplateName];

        if(vendorreviewTemplate != null && VendorReviewIdsList.isEmpty() == false)
        {

            Messaging.MassEmailMessage vendorreviewMail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();

            vendorreviewMail.setTargetObjectIds(VendorReviewIdsList);
            vendorreviewMail.setTemplateId(vendorreviewTemplate.Id);
            vendorreviewMail.setUseSignature(false);
            vendorreviewMail.setSaveAsActivity(true);

        }
        else
        {
            System.Debug('VendorReviewCronJob:sendMail(): Either an email template could not be found, or no Account has a vendor review today');
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Your code is written to fail silently, swallowing exceptions with those try/catch/debug blocks. That makes it difficult to debug. I would recommend removing those try/catch blocks in a sandbox and running the code directly from Execute Anonymous. The results should help you pinpoint where your error is located.

Comment: You also don't do anything with `debugAddress `, so you're not going to get an email one way or the other.

Comment: Thank you @DavidReed.

I've amended my code as per your suggestion, and run the Execute Anonymous, but I'm neither getting any results, or any errors. It just says "EXECUTION_FINISHED". Thoughts?

Comment: Is there any data matching the query in your sandbox?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I ended up going a different route. Instead, I created an schedulable Apex Class just to update a checkbox when the conditions were met, then made a simple workflow to send an email whenever that checkbox is ticked. Works great.